# python tkinter: unresolved functions of text widget

Tags: python, text, widget, tkinter

Can anyone please explain why there are some functions unresolved like insert() and pack() for text widget particularly and there is an error in `text = Text(root)` line? 
I have imported Tkinter and set PYTHONPATH to libs but I still can not run programm normally.
Thank you in advance

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from nltk import *
import sentiment_analysis

root = Tk()
root.title('Semantic Orientation of the Text')

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

text = Text(root)// error
text.tag_config("big", font=('Verdana', 14, 'normal'))
text.tag_config("color", font=('Times New Roman', 24))
text.tag_config("groove", relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=4)
text.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)  #pack() is unresolved

scroll = Tk.Scrollbar(text)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

def onButtonText():

    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/nltk_data/sentiment_analysis')
    text.insert(END, open(filename).read()) #insert() in unresolved
```

There are also other functions for buttons' event handlers but they have the same mistake - insert() for text widget is unresolved

Comment: I am working in pycharm 2.0.2

Comment: What is the code and what is the error? (PYTHONPATH has nothing to do with this as long as you can import Tkinter correctly)

Comment: Please edit your question, you can not put code in a comment, it's not formatted. And what do you mean by "unresolved". What exception is raised?

Comment: Does your actual script have `//error` in it?  That seems like a syntax error to me ...

Comment: I have already figured out the reason: there was a library imported because of which some functions were unresolved(the python did not see them) so I deleted that import and now everything works good :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, since you are doing `import *`, you're importing two versions of Text so you're not getting the object you think you are.

There's really no good reason to do `import *`. Your code will be easier to maintain if you do something like this instead:

```
import Tkinter as tk
...
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for recommendation!